# Get join results grouped by condition with Propel ORM

Tags: php, symfony, propel, silex

I'm trying to get some propel objects populated with some joint data.

the problem:

I have 2 tables, lets call them table a and table b, table A is a parent to table B, the relationship is one to many, where one parent can have many childrens.

I would like to perform a query on the children table, and get its parents, and group the results by the parent id, so later I can print them each child into its parent tab in html.

Here is my schema

```
<table name="countries">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="128" required="true" />
    <column name="country_code" phpName="CountryCode" type="VARCHAR" size="7" required="true" />
    <column name="status" phpName="Status" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false" />

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="soft_delete" />
</table>

<table name="banks">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="128" required="true" />
    <column name="status" phpName="Status" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false" />
    <column name="country_id" phpName="CountryId" type="INTEGER" required="true" />

    <foreign-key foreignTable="countries" phpName="Countries" onDelete="setnull" onUpdate="cascade"><!-- country parent -->
        <reference local="country_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="soft_delete" />
</table>
```

I've been reading a lot without much luck, and to be honest I havent done much testing myself as I dont seem my way out of this.

```
<?php
public function banks(Application $app)
{
    $banks = BanksQuery::create()
        ->where('banks.status = ?', true)
        ->find();
    $nav_options = $this->getNav($app);
    $admin_level = false;
    return $app['twig']->render('admin/banks.twig', array
        (
            'admin_level' => $admin_level,
            'nav_options' => $nav_options,
            'banks' => $banks
            )
        );
}
```

Also tried other ways to build the query, no dice.

```
<?php
$banks = BanksQuery::create()
        ->orderByCountryId()
        ->joinWithCountries('banks.country_id')
        ->where('banks.status = ?', true)
        ->find();
```

The whole idea is to get every children, grouped by every parent, so if I have 3 parents and each parents have between 1 to N childrens, I can then get to print in html, each parent as a tab and its childrens as content for each tab.

if i were to query each parent, it is doable with useCountriesQuery()->filterById(ID-HERE) yet I want to have this on a single sweep.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution doing the query differently.
    leftJoinWithBanks('Banks.CountryId')
            ->orderById()
            ->find();
by querying the countries with a join in banks, i get the info i need, so this works.